# Using Dexie.js in Node.js

Tags: node.js, compatibility, indexeddb, dexie

There seem to be several IndexedDB implementations for Node.js. Is there something suitable that can be used as a drop-in replacement for IndexedDB so that [Dexie.js](http://dexie.org/) can be used in Node.js?

Answer (score 1):

> There seem to be several IndexedDB implementations for Node.js.

There may seem to be, but that is an illusion. [This is the only complete one I'm aware of](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fake-indexeddb) (full disclosure, I wrote it) but you probably don't want to build your app on it, it's way too slow.